# Spatial Audio Head Tracking With AVAudioEngine

Tags: ios, audio, spatial, avaudioengine

I have an AVAudioEngine playing a number of AVAudioPlayerNodes. I'm using AVAudioEnvironmentNode to simulate the positioning of these. The position seems to work correctly. However, I'd like these to work with head tracking so if the user moves their head the sounds from the players move accordingly. I can't figure out for to do it or find any docs on the subject.

Comment: Just had a re-read of this. Are you aiming to do the head tracking with the Air Pod pros?

Comment: Same here. I'm experimenting with you same setup, but can't find documentation about how to activate the head tracking spatial thing. Did you find out?

Answer (score 0):

To track the position of the head, you need to use:
-> `CMHeadphoneMotionManager`
and use the function:
-> `func startDeviceMotionUpdates(to: OperationQueue, withHandler: CMHeadphoneMotionManager.DeviceMotionHandler)`.
The values from `CMDeviceMotion` in DeviceMotionHandler need to be
converted into values for `AVAudioEnvironmentNode`.
(`listenerPosition: AVAudio3DPoint, listenerAngularOrientation: AVAudio3DAngularOrientation, listenerVectorOrientation: AVAudio3DVectorOrientation`)